# Invoking PowerShell through a command prompt does not allow the use of Pipe “|”

Tags: powershell

Invoking PowerShell through a command prompt does not allow the use of Pipe “|”.  As a simple example, the following does not select “FullName”

```
C:>powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -noprofile -noninterac
tive Invoke-Command -Computer Remote.Computer -ScriptBlock { Import-Module
'C:\Scripts\RunVirtualMachineManager.ps1'; ls " | select FullName" }
```

Comment: Why did you insert quotes around `| select FullName`?

Comment: instead of the quotes try sticking a ^ before the pipe to escape it.  For example `echo asd ^| asd` prints `asd | asd`

Comment: The pipe is not being interpreted properly.  If I do a PowerShell command with a select e.g.: “<command> | select count” I get “'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command.”  If I put the carrot, “<command> ^| select count” the command no longer errors, but PowerShell does not then actually select the count.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this, but this looks better:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -noprofile -noninteractive "Invoke-Command -Computer Remote.Computer -ScriptBlock { Import-Module 'C:\Scripts\RunVirtualMachineManager.ps1'; ls | select FullName }"
```

Shouldn't the module you're trying to import end in .psm1?

For example, this works for me:

```
powershell -Executionpolicy RemoteSigned -noprofile -noninteractive "Get-Process | Select ProcessName"
```

The command you want to run, including the pipe, all goes inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The following cleansed version worked for us (using a 'select count' example):
C:>powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -noprofile -noninteractive "&{Invoke-Command -Computer Remote.Computer -ScriptBlock { Import-Module 'C:\\.ps1' | Out-Null;  | select Count | Format-List }}"